# iOS Testing: Issues with UITextField testing with KIF

Tags: ios, testing, integration-testing, kif-framework

I am trying out KIF for iOS testing and am having trouble with UITextField interactions.

I am using the following code for adding text in a textfield.

```
KIFTestScenario *scenario = [KIFTestScenario scenarioWithDescription:@"Test that a user can successfully log in."];
[steps addObject:[KIFTestStep stepToEnterText:@"test text" intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"username"]];
```

The problem is that, this method responds if 'username' text is the value of textfield, instead if its ID or label as it might seem.
Is there a way by which I could access the textfield with its ID / label? (since I intend to have my textfield empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that as long as you don't set an accessibilityLabel yourself, the UITextField uses its text value as accessibilityLabel.

Set the accessibilityLabel of the TextField and you should be fine.

```
textField.accessibilityLabel = @"test text";
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, I would have to update my code to set accessibilityLabels for all UI elements. Is there a way to access UI elements with any other reference other than the accesibilityLabel?

Comment: You'd have to write your own KIFTestSteps for that, the supplied steps mostly only handle accessibilityLabel. Also, your views should have accessibility labels anyway to satisfy disabled users.